# Pass multiline string to sqlplus in unix

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sqlplus

I am trying to declare few variables in sqlplus in unix at runtime but the string is in single line and causing error. I need the string to be a multiline string

Code snippet:

```
#this string is generated at runtime
OUT_DECLARE_STRING="variable IO_TABLE_NAME varchar2(4000); variable O_NROFROWS varchar2(4000); variable O_OUTPUTSTATUS varchar2(4000); variable O_OUTPUTMESSAGE varchar2(4000); variable O_OUTSUMMARYDATE varchar2(4000); variable O_SORT_ORDER varchar2(4000); variable O_RECORD_LIMIT varchar2(4000); variable O_SELECTED_COLUMNS varchar2(4000);"
```

Now I am passing this OUT_DECLARE_STRING to sqlplus as

```
QUERY_RESULT=`sqlplus -s $USER_NAME/$PASSWORD@$SERVICE_NAME <<EOF
$OUT_DECLARE_STRING
exec $OWNER.$PROCEDURE_NAME($I_PARAMETER,$O_PARAMETER);
select $OUTPUT from dual;
COMMIT;
EXIT;
EOF`
```

I am getting error as :

Usage: VAR[IABLE] [  [ NUMBER | CHAR | CHAR (n [CHAR|BYTE]) | VARCHAR2 (n [CHAR|BYTE]) | NCHAR | NCHAR (n) | NVARCHAR2 (n) | CLOB | NCLOB | BLOB | BFILE REFCURSOR | BINARY_FLOAT | BINARY_DOUBLE ] ] SP2-0552: Bind variable "O_OUTSUMMARYDATE" not declared.

Can somebody help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Use awk for splitting string by ';' separator. FS is field separator. NF is fields count. $i is particular field.

```
OUT_DECLARE_STRING=$(echo $OUT_DECLARE_STRING | awk 'BEGIN {FS=";"} {for (i=0; i<NF; i+=1) print $i ";"}')
QUERY_RESULT=`sqlplus -s $USER_NAME/$PASSWORD@$SERVICE_NAME <<EOF
$OUT_DECLARE_STRING
exec $OWNER.$PROCEDURE_NAME($I_PARAMETER,$O_PARAMETER);
select $OUTPUT from dual;
COMMIT;
EXIT;
EOF`
```